# Liferay Customization of Management Pages

Tags: java, liferay

I'd like to understand how can I customize different pages in the Liferay management screens. For example:

1. I'd like to add a few fields to images that are being uploaded to the *Image Gallery*
2. I'd like to add new field types that I can use when creating new *structures* (for example, add a "phone number" field type so I can add it to new structures I'd like to create).
3. Another example would be to customize the *Web Content* search page and add/remove fields and customize it's look & feel.

Any pointers would be helpful, as I've read most of the stuff about developing for Liferay but could figure our where to start with doing stuff like that (without changing core Liferay files)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think 2) can be done without changing Liferay itself (e.g. patching the source code).

You can customize all built-in JSP pages using so called "JSP Hooks". I have done that to customize the pages for the user administration (mainly removing confusing fields from them).

The basic idea is to provide a modified version of the core JSP page. Upon deploying the hook, Liferay will replace the built-in page with the customized version. When the hook is undeployed, Liferay activates the original page again.

The following pages should have enough information to get you started:

http://www.liferay.com/web/guest/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Portal+Hook+Plugins
http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/1071674/Custom+Fields+and+JSP+Hooks
http://wikis.sun.com/display/websynergy/Customizing+JSPs+using+hooks+plugin

Make sure you search in the Liferay forum as well.